# How can I only read out a list after all forEach passes?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I want to upload multiple images to Firebase Storage and get the URL of each one. I use a task for this. So far everything works. But how can I only read out the list with the URLs when the task forEach is finished? It is currently the case that the list is only output in the log, it is empty, and then it is jumped to forEach:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask>(tasks).addOnSuccessListener {
    val downloadUrls = mutableListOf<String>()

    tasks.forEach {
        it.result.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { snap->
            downloadUrls.add(snap.toString())
            Log.e("Downloadable Image URL",snap.toString())
        }
    }
    
    //The list here is empty
    Log.d("List with URLs",downloadUrls.toString())
    progressDialog.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: Not after the last forEach() but after the last add(). You do it now before the first add().

Comment: You have to do it inside the listener. The code after the listener is called *before* the code inside the listener because the listener code is called in the future, after the data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you're calling:

```
Log.d("List with URLs",downloadUrls.toString())
```

The operation of adding files to Storage isn't completed yet. So that's the reason why you get an empty list. If you want to see the content of the `downloadUrls` list, you have to use that log statement only when the operations are 100% complete. Now, since you're using Kotlin, I recommend you use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines). So your code can be written as simple as:

```
val downloadUrls = mutableListOf<String>()
val listOfTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask>(tasks).await()
listOfTasks.forEach {
    val downloadUrl = it.result.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.await()
    downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl)
}
Log.d("List with URLs",downloadUrls.toString())
```

Comment: Hey Captai-N. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?